# Vim: What's the difference between 'DoMatchParen' and the showmatch option?

Tags: vim

I've heard plenty of both, but I can't really test how they're different.

For example, if I have MatchParen activated (on by default, or doing `:DoMatchParen`) the cursor changes color when on top of a bracket of some kind, the matching bracket does the same.

I also get `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` effects. Although these are present always I've noticed, even if I use `:NoMatchParen`, correct me if I'm wrong.

However, if in my .vimrc file I have `set showmatch`, I don't really notice any difference whatsoever, even if I disable MatchParen with `:NoMatchParen`.

So my question is, what are the differences between these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- With `showmatch` enabled, when you enter a close-bracket, the cursor briefly jumps to the matching open-bracket. This is only done when entering the text (i.e. in insert mode).
- With `MatchParen` activated, if the cursor is over a bracket, its matching partner is highlighted (in insert mode or normal mode).

The two are independent of one another.

Comment: Excellent, that answers my question. Thanks!